# The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type Text

Tags: c#, sql, .net, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML and get all the info from it using XMLreader. It's throwing the error from the title for some reason. Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<queries>
  <selectparent table="Associates">"SELECT * FROM @table"</selectparent>
  <selectchild table="VehicleContract">"SELECT * FROM @table"</selectchild>
  <addchild table="VehicleContract" read="contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr">"INSERT into @table (contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr) VALUES (@id, @reg, @assort, @perc, @type, @trailer)"</addchild>
  <updatechild table="VehicleContract" read="contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr">"UPDATE @table SET regNr=@reg, assoc_id=@assort, percentage=@perc, vehicleType=@type, trailerNr=@trailer WHERE contractId=@id"</updatechild>
  <removechild table="VehicleContract" read="id">"DELETE from @table WHERE contractId=@id"</removechild>
</queries>
```

And my method:

```
public string selectParent, selectChildren, addChildren, updateChildren, removeChildren;
public string[] addParams, updateParams, removeParams;
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(base.Path);
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
reader.Read();
reader.Read(); 
reader.Read();
selectParent = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
reader.Read();
selectChildren = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
addParams = reader.GetAttribute("read").Split(',');
addChildren = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
updateParams = reader.GetAttribute("read").Split(',');
updateChildren = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
removeParams = reader.GetAttribute("read").Split(',');
removeChildren = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
```

I get the error on this line:
 `selectParent = reader.ReadElementContentAsString`
What's the problem? I kept adding `reader.Read()` because I kept getting the same error but on different node types.

As far as I know, the table attribute should replace the @table from the query... but something is not right. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check that `base.Path` is referring to the expected XML file. Your code works for me when I embed the XML as a string and load it into the reader using `new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml))`. Also, if you can debug your code and look at `reader.NodeType` and `reader.Name`, that will tell you where you are in the file.

Comment: I used the full path and in the debugger, it takes me to the xml. When I get to that line, it shows  >"SELECT * FROM @table"</ and then throws the error :/

Answer (score 0):

I would use xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                "<queries>" +
                  "<selectparent table=\"Associates\">\"SELECT * FROM @table\"</selectparent>" +
                  "<selectchild table=\"VehicleContract\">\"SELECT * FROM @table\"</selectchild>" +
                  "<addchild table=\"VehicleContract\" read=\"contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr\">\"INSERT into @table (contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr) VALUES (@id, @reg, @assort, @perc, @type, @trailer)\"</addchild>" +
                  "<updatechild table=\"VehicleContract\" read=\"contractId, regNr, assoc_id, percentage, vehicleType, trailerNr\">\"UPDATE @table SET regNr=@reg, assoc_id=@assort, percentage=@perc, vehicleType=@type, trailerNr=@trailer WHERE contractId=@id\"</updatechild>" +
                  "<removechild table=\"VehicleContract\" read=\"id\">\"DELETE from @table WHERE contractId=@id\"</removechild>" +
                "</queries>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Elements("queries").Select(x => new
            {
                selectParent = x.Elements("selectparent").Select(y => new
                {
                    table = (string)y.Attribute("table"),
                    value = y.Value
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                selectChild = x.Elements("selectchild").Select(y => new
                {
                    table = (string)y.Attribute("table"),
                    value = y.Value
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                addChild = x.Elements("addchild").Select(y => new
                {
                    table = (string)y.Attribute("table"),
                    read = (string)y.Attribute("read"),
                    value = y.Value
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                updateChild = x.Elements("updatechild").Select(y => new
                {
                    table = (string)y.Attribute("table"),
                    read = (string)y.Attribute("read"),
                    value = y.Value
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
                removeChild = x.Elements("removechild").Select(y => new
                {
                    table = (string)y.Attribute("table"),
                    read = (string)y.Attribute("read"),
                    value = y.Value
                }).FirstOrDefault(),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use Linq of any kind so at the moment, I'm really trying to figure why my code isn't working

Comment: You should create a class to hold all the results.  Then I would find out if XElement class is considered linq.  The XElement class is an enhanced version of the XmlElement class.